# how to select text naturally with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Due to copyright laws and licensing agreements, I'm unable to allow copy+paste on certain parts of text we're displaying.  So selecting is disabled and right click is disabled.  It sucks, I know, but unfortunately its part of playing the game and remaining in business.

With jquery, I've been able to allow the user to select text line by line -- that is, they mouseover a line of text, it gets highlighted and if they click it, then it permamently gets selected which causes a 'copy' button to appear.

I want to this but allow partial lines to be selected.  So if the user only wants to copy two words from the line, they can.  More like the natural selection process.

I'm having difficulty doing this.  In my whole line solution, I add divs around each line.  But this doesn't seem efficient for partial lines?  Would I have to have spans around each word?

Any other ideas?

Comment: `<rant>`Disabling selecting text and right-click is such an idiotic feature of security theatre. If the information is displayed to the user, the game is lost. View the page source, or disable JavaScript, and all that "security" evaporates, to say nothing of `wget` or text-only browsers.`</rant>`

Comment: You shouldn't ever have to disable right click or selecting. Stop being conferment and write websites that don't suck

Comment: Disabling right click won't people stop copying stuff from your website. May I ask, on what kind of website you want to use this? Maybe there's a much nicer way.

Comment: When you're getting sued into oblivion and the industry you're in is a version of OPEC, you have to play the game.

Comment: or option > disable javascript. (or like me: unbind the right click event with a console command ^^). But it's not the subject. where is my fiddle?

Comment: I honestly don't care if the users find ways around copying.  If I'm told to "disable right click, disable selection" I'm going to do the absolute min to comply.  I don't like the restriction but its either this or shut down entirely -- or get sued into oblivion.

Comment: @Mike then give up on this "natural text selection" hootenanny, and just leave all text unselectable.

Comment: @Sn0opy: we're a lyrics website who recently licensed content (aka we're now legal)

Comment: The best way to handle this is with a copyright notice or a site usage agreement.  If someone is stealing your content, they are the ones that are accountable.  If you client is going to sue you for people stealing your content you are screwed no matter what you do.  Circumventing this would be trivially easy, so you are still liable.

Comment: Bottom line: you have agreed to do something that is impossible. As stated above, no matter what you do to prevent copy/paste, there are several ways to circumvent that. I would renegotiate the license before moving further, as you are likely at risk for getting sued no matter what you do.

Comment: Have you hired a copyright attorney to explain what you are actually liable for?  That is the first thing you should have done.

Comment: We're allowed to copy upto 160 characters or 4 lines of text.  So this is what I'm trying to accomplish ideally.

Comment: Don't forget, you also need to come up with a solution to prevent someone from taking screenshots of the page.  Good luck with that.

Comment: I am liable for disabling selection for the purpose of 1) right clicking and copying 2) pressing ctrl+c 3) going up to edit and clicking copy.  Anything else is fair game and they know this, they just want the 'easiest' copying solutions removed.

Answer (score 6):

You don't, you enable selection. Problem solved.

If this gives you legal trouble, get a good lawyer.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to prevent copy and paste is to serve your text as an image. Any other attempt to prevent it is so easily circumventable that it might as well not exist.

Turning off JavaScript, Greasemonkey scripts, custom browser addons, view source, wget will all be available.

If your contract explicitly says "disable copy and paste for more than x characters" then fineyou're going to the letter of a contract that was badly worded but if your contract says "prevent copy and paste of over x words" then you need to talk to your legal team because that is an impossible request, you may even open yourself up to being sued by claiming to do this wtih full knowledge that there are these workarounds.

Comment: I don't think rendering as an image offers any legal protection.  Copying the image wouldn't be any different than copying the raw text.

Comment: @mikerobi I was referring more to how to disable copy and paste of text itself and that none of the other options actually do this, but yes this is itself something that can be copied and pasted, manually typed out or even run through OCR. Furthering the overall point that the actual contractual requests, depending on the exact wording, may be technically impossible.